# How to typecast and inherit Rust structs?

Tags: struct, rust

**Note:** This was asked about a pre-1.0 version of Rust, involving a feature which has since been withdrawn from the language.

---

I am using the experimental feature `feature(struct_inherit)`.

I have the `LocalPlayer` and `NetPlayer` structs and they both implement the `Inputable` trait as well as inherit the `player_num` field from the virtual struct `Player`. Depending on how a game starts, `player_2` in my program can either be a `LocalPlayer` or `NetPlayer`. Depending on which one, the way that the `Inputable` trait is implemented changes.

The compiler won't let me dynamically assign `player_2` a type depending on whether it's a `NetPlayer` or `LocalPlayer`. It complains:

> error: mismatched types: expected `~player::LocalPlayer` but found `~player::NetPlayer` (expected struct player::LocalPlayer but found struct player::NetPlayer)

It also won't let me typecast `NetPlayer` or `LocalPlayer` pointers to a `Player` pointer. It claims they aren't scalable.

The code sample in question is as follows:

```rust
let player1 = box player::LocalPlayer::new(0);
let player2;
if local {
    player2 = box player::LocalPlayer::new(1);
} else if hosting {
    player2 = box player::NetPlayer::new(1);
    player2.host();
} else {
    player2 = box player::NetPlayer::new(1);
    player2.connect();
}
/* ... Omitted Code ... */
let input = player2.get_input(); // Trait function
```

The struct implementations are as follows:

```rust
pub virtual struct Player {
    player_num: uint
}
pub struct LocalPlayer: Player;
pub struct NetPlayer: Player;
```

Comment: Since when Rust has virtual structs and struct inheritance? o_O As far as I know, various RFCs on this are still pending.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev: it’s a partially implemented feature which can’t yet do what is being asked, as far as I know.

Comment: I was using the experiment feature via #![feature(struct_inherit)]

Comment: @ChrisMorgan, it's strange that it wasn't advertised at all.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev: there’s a reason for that.

Answer (score 6):

Struct inheritance in Rust is very primitive; you probably don't want to use it. There is no subtyping or coercion between inheriting structs in Rust. The feature basically just allows you to save typing if you have a lot of structs with similar fields (it's also future proofing for maybe adding more features around them in the future).

You could make `Player`, `LocalPlayer` and `NetPlayer` traits. You then get the subtyping behaviour you want between them. Alternatively, you could make just `LocalPlayer` and `NetPlayer` structs and let `Player` be a trait. You could even have a `PlayerImpl` struct which you could inherit from the way you do currently (if you have a lot of fields to share), but you would need to write independent impls for both structs.

Comment: But say I want to use struct inheritance only to "embed" fields of the parent struct in the child struct. I do in fact want to have primitive struct inheritance. How do I do this? There's no documentation to find about this.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up implementing `Player` as an enum:

```
pub enum Player {
    Net(NetPlayer),
    Local(LocalPlayer)
}
```

Every time I call a shared function, I need to do the following:

```
let input = match player2 {
    player::Net(player) => player.get_input(),
    player::Local(player) => player.get_input(),
};
```

Comment: You can implement methods on an enum, you know: e.g. `impl Player { fn get_input(&self) -> ? { match *self { Net(ref player) => player.get_input(), Local(ref player) => player.get_input() } } }`

Answer (score 4):

Rust's traits are similar to interfaces, and can be composed to emulate a hierarchy of interfaces. They're often an alternative to inheritance:

```
trait GetInput {
    fn get_input(&self);
}

impl GetInput for Player {
    fn get_input(&self) {}
}

impl GetInput for NetPlayer {
    fn get_input(&self) {}
}

// Fast: interface selected at compile time
fn do_something<T: GetInput>(player: T) {
    player.get_input();
}

// Flexible: interface selected at run time (virtual call)
// Use with Box<Player> (see "Trait Objects")
fn do_something_dyn(player: &dyn GetInput) {
    player.get_input();
}
```

However, Rust doesn't have inheritance of *data*. To have common fields shared between types, you need some alternative DIY solution (e.g. getters/setters in traits or structs with enums).